# How can I select columns by type in a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

As the title says, I have a polymorphic relationship of many to many, I want to select certain columns of each model. I have already looked at the documentation of Laravel but I only found this code, which is similar to what I am looking for.

```php
$comments = App\Comment::whereHasMorph(
    'commentable', 
    ['App\Post', 'App\Video'], 
    function (Builder $query, $type) {

        if ($type === 'App\Post') {
            $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
        }
    }
)->get();
```

I want to do something similar but this way:

```php
$comments = App\Comment::with(
    'commentable', 
    ['App\Post', 'App\Video'], 
    function (Builder $query, $type) {
        if ($type === 'App\Post') {
            $query->select('id', 'title');
        }elseif($type === 'App\Video'){
           $query->select('id', 'name');
        }
    }
)->get();
```

I hope you can understand me and help with this problem thanks

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. Can someone please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the polymorphic method in each Model classes looks like this:

```
public function commentType() 
{ 
    return $this->morphOne('App\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

An easy way would be to add two methods to the Comment class:

public function getIsPostAttribute()
   {
       return $this->commentType == 'App\Post';
   }

public function getIsVideoAttribute()
   {
       return $this->commentType == 'App\Video';
   }

Then, just:

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1)->isPost; // True or False
$comment = App\Comment::find(1)->isVideo; // True or False
```

Now queries will be easy to do:

```
$posts  = App\Comment::where('isPost', true)->get();
$videos = App\Comment::where('isVideo', true)->get();
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, I want all the comments in one query, and each model by selecting certain columns